# An appropriate synonym for “the use of” in the context

Tags: grammar, synonyms

> Also, **the use of** commonly available solutions contributed to cost reduction.

Which synonym, term or phrase can I use instead of 'the use of' to create a sentence?

Comment: I hear businessy people say “leveraging” for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say:

> Also, the implementation of commonly available solutions contributed to cost reduction.

*Employment* might also be OK but it sounds a bit weird. Kind of depends on what the "solutions" are.

Answer (score 0):

You could also say "making use of", "using", "the employment of", or "employing" (which doesn't sound weird to me, personally), "the application of" or "applying", "availing oursevles of", and "the adoption of" or "adopting", among others.

With no disrespect to user3169's position (there's no real right or wrong here), "implementation" sounds like it has a slightly different flavor of meaning to me, having a sense of "installation" which "use" doesn't.  Perhaps it's a bias from my profession (I'm a software developer); we implement solutions by designing, creating, and delivering them.  So, implementation has a rather narrow meaning in my profession.

Comment: The phrase refers to "cost reduction" which to me means something changed. So it was not just the same old thing they were doing/using, which is why I thought of implementation. It would be helpful to know what the "solutions" were, though as you mention it sounds like software.

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful to know.  If the solution were to implement an "austerity program" of some sort, then implementation is a good word.